# RegEx to find all possible relative links to a specific file - also capture link text

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

Yes, there's hundreds of [regex] [html] topics on SO, but the first 30 I've checked don't help me with my problem.

I've got 745 total links (all relative, and they have to stay relative) to a file in my site. I need to find all these links and append data before and after them. I also need to capture and use the link text.

I've tried several expressions and the regex below is the closest I can get, but it's not good enough - it keeps finding a few instances of some other href to a different file and captures the content all the way to the `</a>` of the file I actually care about.

```
<a href="((.)*?)?myFile.html((.)*?)?>((.)*?)?</a>
```

In the above, I need to capture the relative path to the file and any anchors that might be present, as well as the actual link text.

What regex *should* I be using?

It shouldn't matter, but I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver to perform the search.

Comment: Just anchors `#` or any query string `?`. Is `myFile.html` just an example and the regex needs to just ignore this portion?

Comment: Please, give us two examples and what exactly you need to capture from both of them.

Comment: I need to find things like `<a href="a.fparameters.html#jobmaxnodecount">JOBMAXNODECOUNT</a>` and `<a href="../../a.fparameters.html#accountcfg">ACCOUNTCFG</a>`
I need to capture the relative path, any anchors after the file, and I need the content in the link text.

Comment: It should only be anchors after the filename. No queries.

Comment: @MikeK. Check my answer. If you only want to match `a.fparameters.html` files, let me know and I'll edit it.

Comment: @OscarMederos - Yes, that is exactly the behavior I want. If the file name doesn't match `a.fparameters`, I don't care about the result.

Comment: does a line always start with `a href...`? If so, edit the regex to enforce a start of line at the beginning of the expression using the carat like `^<a href`. Then it won't capture 2 anchors.

Comment: No, I'm afraid the links are almost always inline.

Comment: @MikeK. Could you please check my last edit?

Comment: @OscarMederos, sorry, I was in a meeting. To everyone else - I'm surprised at how difficult this issue was. I was thinking it would be a very simple expression and that I was overlooking something obvious. I'm not a regexpert and I see that I would never have come to this answer on my own. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work for what you need:

```
<a href="([^"]*?a\.fparameters\.html)(#[^"]+?)?".*?>(.*?)<
```

It will work even if you have URLs like:

```
<a href="a.fparameters.html">JOBMAXNODECOUNT</a>
```

that do not have `#xxxx`.

**A few examples:**

For `<a href="a.fparameters.html#jobmaxnodecount">JOBMAXNODECOUNT</a>`you will get:

- Group 1: `a.fparameters.html`
- Group 2: `#jobmaxnodecount`
- Group 3: `JOBMAXNODECOUNT`

For `<a href="commands/mjobctl.html#modify">mjobctl -m</a> to modify the job after it has been submitted. See the <a href="a.fparameters.html#rsvsearchalgo">RSVSEARCHALGO</a>` you will get only **one match**:

- Group 1: `a.fparameters.html`
- Group 2: `#rsvsearchalgo`
- Group 3: `RSVSEARCHALGO`

Comment: Right, but I don't want it to find the first match - I want it to return: Group 1: `<any path to ONLY this file>a.fparameters`, Group 2: `an anchor` (if any), and Group 3: `the link text`. This solution is very close, but is finding all links, instead of JUST links to the specific file, `a.fparameters`.

Comment: @MikeK. That's not a problem. Let me modify it.

Comment: @MikeK. Check now. Also, perhaps you want to exclude the `#` from the 2nd group?

Comment: For Group 2, almost all the links to this file contain anchors, occasionally they will not. I ALWAYS need to capture the anchor if it does exist. The updated expression still isn't quite working - it returned a result like this: `<a href="topics/resourceManagers/rmconfiguration.html#version">VERSION</a> should be set as an attribute on the <a href="a.fparameters.html#rmcfg">RMCFG<`

Comment: Good point. `<a href="([^"]*?a\.fparameters\.html)(#[^"]+?)?".*?>(.*?)<`

Comment: @MikeK. When I said *exclude `#` from the 2nd group* I meant to return `rsvsearchalgo` instead of `#rsvsearchalgo`.

Comment: I see what you mean now - I misread your other comment. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @MikeK. If you want to exclude the `#`, you can use: `<a href="([^"]*?a\.fparameters\.html)(?:#([^"]+?))?".*?>(.*?)<`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: (updated)

```
href="([^"]*?)myFile\.html#?([^"]*).*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/lA6vB7

Comment: This is having the same problem my original expression has (minus the fact that I forgot to escape the forward slash) - It occasionally finds some other `<a href>` that occurs BEFORE the one I care about, and captures all content from the start of the first one, to the `</a>` of the one I care about.

P.S. That website is awesome! Thanks for the link!

Comment: For example, it found this as a match: `<a href="commands/mjobctl.html#modify">mjobctl -m</a> to modify the job after it has been submitted. See the <a href="a.fparameters.html#rsvsearchalgo">RSVSEARCHALGO</a>`

Comment: I appreciate your help - but Oscar's answer came about 10 minutes before yours. I still +1'd you because of the great resource you linked to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

First, never do this: `(.)*` ...or this: `(?:.)*`

The first one consumes one character at a time and captures it in a group, each time overwriting previous captured character.  The second one avoids most of that overhead by using a non-capturing group, but it's still only matching one character at a time inside that group; why bother?  All it's doing is cluttering up the regex.

Adding the `?` to make it non-greedy -- e.g. `(.)*?`-- doesn't make it worse, but it doesn't help, either.  And sticking that inside another group and making the group optional -- i.e. `((.)*?)?` -- is a recipe for [catastrophic backtracking.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  But performance considerations aside, when I see a capturing group with a quantifier attached, it almost always turns out mistake on the author's part. ([ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html))

As for your question, my solution turns out to be almost identical to [Oscar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14841200/20938):

```
<a href="([^#"]*?a\.fparameters\.html)(?:#([^"]*))?">([^<>]*)</a>
```